# Exclude duplicate entry on two aar Android

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I have used 2 third party **aar** dependencies in my Android Project and

they both are using same Encoding Library called `org.spongycastle.util`.

But problem here is when i compiled it it shows an Error on Gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/spongycastle/util/encoders/Base64.class
```

I tried to exclude one dependency from aar on Gradle complie by

```
compile(name: 'libraryname', ext: 'aar') {
    exclude group: 'org.spongycastle.util'
}
```

But no luck of solving issue :(

Any help would be appreciated to exclude or ignore one dependency

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue eventually? I'm stuck with this identical error.

Comment: Hi mate I solved it by changing the class names of the SpongyCastle  as I couldn't manage to `exclude org.spongycastle` on aar.Its not recommended way but it works.

Comment: cool, but can you explain what do you exactly mean by changing the class names? I mean, I just have two aars in my project and both have Spongycastle jars under the hood and use them internally, I don't need to use anything from Spongycastle explicitly.

Comment: For my situation I clone the source code of  aar and change the class name ,build the release aar again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the jar file org.spongycastle.util itself contains the duplicate entry. I've seen this same issue in an xmlbean jar file. Android however doesn't like the duplicate entry. One way to get around this is to download that particular jar file and delete one of the duplicate entries and add the modified jar to your libs folder. Additionally, you'll need to exclude it from the appropriate compile dependency it is associated with.  You'll need to test to be sure that deleting one of the duplicates doesn't break anything.  If the contents of the two duplicate classes are equivalent, then deleting one of the duplicates wouldn't have any consequence.